# Construcción de la expresión "No hay mal que por bien no venga"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, expresiones, sintaxis

Aunque creo que entiendo el significado, la forma en la que está construida la frase me resulta rara. El principio ["No hay mal que ...] es una forma común en expresiones y refranes, pero tengo problemas con el final ["que por bien no venga"].

Para hacerla más fácilmente comprensible (y con una forma más habitual) tendría que convertirla en "No hay ningún mal que no acabe por dar lugar a un bien", lo que supone un cambio en el orden de la parte final y deshacer elipsis (*ningún*, *acabe*) y cambiar el verbo *venir* a una de sus acepciones (*dar lugar a*).

Todo ello hace que me parezca una construcción rara en una expresión que por otro lado parece ser muy corriente.

Las preguntas que me planteo son:
¿Es correcta la conversión que he hecho?
¿Esa construcción era habitual en su época? (Hay una obra de Ruiz de Alarcón con ese título, anterior a 1630 según [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_hay_mal_que_por_bien_no_venga), lo que hace suponer que es anterior a esa fecha?
¿Este tipo de construcción se utiliza en otras expresiones hoy día?

Answer (score 6):

Si nos fijamos en este tipo de aforismos (*refranes*, *proverbios*, *máximas*,...) descubriremos que tienen cierta musicalidad. Tienen una estructura lírica. Más cercana al verso que a la prosa.

Hay solemnidad en estas frases. Quizá para que el mensaje cale más hondo en las personas, para que perdure en la memoria colectiva y con ello, en el tiempo.

Si buscamos por [Lírica tradicional](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%ADrica_tradicional)
encontraremos:

> **Géneros**
>   [...]
>   Cantos didácticos: los **refranes**, el **proverbio**, el cuento de animales o fábula.

Si enlazamos con [Proverbio](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proverbio)

> El proverbio (del latín *proverbium*) es un tipo de paremia, un
>   **enunciado sentencioso**. Otros **enunciados sentenciosos**
>   son: **refrán**, adagio, máxima, sentencia, aforismo, frase
>   proverbial, apotegma

Y...

> Su estructura suele ser pareada y recurren tanto a la prosa y verso
>   como a figuras literarias (antítesis, elipsis o paralelismo) para
>   facilitar su perpetuación oral.

Es decir, su estructura es intencionada. Importa el *qué* y el *cómo* se dice.

Para entrar en profundidad en este tipo de estructuras podemos recurrir a la [Paremiología](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paremiolog%C3%ADa)

En referencia a tus preguntas:

> ¿Es correcta la conversión que he hecho?

Sí, yo creo que es correcta, demasiado correcta. Pensemos en el contexto. Es una frase de consolación, la manera "correcta" quizá le haría perder fuerza al mensaje. Demasiado aséptica para alguien que necesita consuelo.

> ¿Este tipo de construcción se utiliza en otras expresiones hoy día?

No hablamos en verso todo el día, pero sí hacemos uso de frases hechas y refranes. Para que un aforismo de este tipo llegue a nuestros días es necesario que perdure en la memoria colectiva. Esto solo es posible si se siguen usando y se transmiten.
Esto sucede frecuentemente en los nucleos familiares y es un método efectivo de transmitir ideas y conocimientos con pocas y sencillas palabras a los más pequeños (con menos vocabulario).

Expresiones como:

- No por correr se llega antes
- No por madrugar amanece antes
- Cuando una puerta se cierra otra se abre (o una ventana se abre)
- Más vale pájaro en mano que ciento volando

Y muchas otras aún se escuchan

---

### **Anexo**

Buscando el *porqué* de la lírica en los aforismos he encontrado textos que bien merecen la pena ser leidos (*los iré añadiendo de a poco*):

[El lenguaje de los aforismos](http://www.poemas-del-alma.com/blog/especiales/el-lenguaje-de-los-aforismos)

Comment: Nótese que la recompensa fue asignada a la otra respuesta automáticamente. ¿Por qué? Porque quien la ofrecía eliminó su cuenta, por lo que no pudo otorgarla directamente. En este caso, se otorga a la respuesta más votada de las que se publican durante el tiempo en que la recompensa está abierta.

Answer (score 1):

El uso de este tipo de frases es muy común y familiar, sobre todo en las familias latinoamericanas, cuya dinámica social implica frecuentemente la convivencia con la familia extendida, de esta manera los niños que están desarrollando su vocabulario tienen la oportunidad de enriquecerlo con los refranes, dichos y palabras que otrora fueran mas populares, al conversar con abuelo.

La frase "*No hay mal que por bien no venga*" es una o de esos **refranes** que en una *corta* frase, *memorable* y *directa* dejan una *enseñanza profunda*.

En este caso, Para cualquier hispanoparlante, el sentido de la frase, siempre es claro: Cuando sufrimos una calamidad, debemos tener la certeza que a cambio, habra una recompensa: es una frase de anhelo, apoyo y esperanza; usada para reconfortar a quien esta pasando por "un mal" recordandole que todo mal resulta en algo bueno.

Una expresion totalmente equivalente en ingles es "***Every cloud has a silver lining***": ("Toda nube esta forrada de plata"): de nuevo transmite esperanza: Aun que la nube tape el sol, lo veremos reflejado tarde o temprano en el forro de plata que portan todas las nubes.

Respecto a tus preguntas:

**¿Es correcta la conversión que he hecho?**

> Totalmente, tal vez no conectaste con la expresión equivalente en tu idioma. >Suele suceder con las expresiones idiomáticas: "*Its raining cats and dogs*" >Literalmente es "*Llueven perros y gatos"* pero la expresión idiomática correcta es "*Esta lloviendo a cántaros*" (Literalmente: "*Its raining by the potful*")

**¿Esa construcción era habitual en su época?**

> Sigue siendo una frase vigente, y muy socorrida en todos los niveles socioeconomicos del mundo hispanoparlante y cualquiera reconoceria el significado. En el caribe (Colombia, Cuba, Puerto Rico) se acostumbra cerrar el circulo de la frase: ***No hay mal que por bien no venga, ni bien que su mal no tenga***

**¿Este tipo de construcción se utiliza en otras expresiones hoy día?**

> Desde luego, hay toda una gama de expresiones idiomaticas, refranes y dichos que siguen ese estilo barroco y curioso para transmitir en pocas palabras un gran contenido, desarrollado previamente por el entorno cultural. Viene a la mente, hyablando de esperanza:

- Cuando Dios cierra una puerta, siempre abre una ventana.
- No por mucho madrugar, amanece mas temprano
- Ni tanto que queme al santo, ni tanto que no lo alumbre

Literalmente:

- When God shuts a door, He also always opens a window
- The sun will not rise earlier no matter how much you try to beat it
- Not so close that the saint would catch fire, nor so far that its overshadowed.

Con los sentidos:

- **Esperanza**, pierdes una oportunidad por voluntad divina, pero hay siempre otra, solo hay que buscar.
- **Esfuerzos mal dirigidos**: El sol siempre saldrá a la hora que sale, sin importar los esfuerzos que uno mismo haga por levantarse mas temprano.
- **Moderación**: (este es uno de mis favoritos, se refiere a las veladoras que se acostumbra encender para orar y honrar a algún santo de la iglesia católica, pues es tradición que cada uno de estos santos concede favores específicos, por ejemplo, *San Antonio encuentra pareja a los solteros*. La mesura se implica al recordar que por mucha urgencia de recibir un favor, no debemos acercar la vela a la figura del santo como para que le prenda fuego, ni debemos dejarla tan lejos, de manera que la figura del santo queda en la oscuridad. De igual manera, al pedir por ejemplo un aumento salarial, hay que hacerlo amablemente y con moderacion y firmeza: no timida mente (no le da la luz al santo) ni exigiendo con  arrogancia (quemando al santo).

Mi fuente es el **[El refranero multilingue](http://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/refranero/Ficha.aspx?Par=59187&Lng=0) del [Instituto Virtual Cervantes](http://cvc.cervantes.es)** un invaluable recurso que nos presenta expresiones sinonimas en varios idiomas.

Comment: Hare la traduccion de manera que la respuesta tenga parte en ingles en unos minutos, solo queria entrar a tiempo para el *bounty* n.n